# PowerShell script to create a list and add a lookup column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, powershell, lookup-column

I need a Script to create a custom list and add a look up column into it and add the column into a default view. The look up column should have relationship of Restrict delete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Adding List**

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://url"
$spTemplate = $spWeb.ListTemplates["Custom List"] 
$spListCollection = $spWeb.Lists 
$spListCollection.Add("listName", "listName", $spTemplate)
```

**Adding Lookup Field with Restrict Delete**

```
$ParentList = $spWeb.Lists.item("ParentList")
$spList = $WebObj.Lists["listName"]
$spList.Fields.AddLookup("ChildLookupField",$ParentList.id,$false)
$spChildListLookupField = $spList.Fields["ChildLookupField"]
$spChildListLookupField.LookupField = $ParentList.Fields["ParentLookupField"]
$spChildListLookupField.RelationshipDeleteBehavior = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRelationshipDeleteBehavior]::Restrict
$spChildListLookupField.Update()
```

**Adding field to View**

```
$spView = $spList.DefaultView
$spView.ViewFields.add($spChildListLookupField)
$spView.Update()
```

Comment: @mak do not forget to mark as answer if it solves your problem. (I think your answer is pretty good)

Comment: what is $WebObj?